# C# streamreader split question

Tags: c#

What i'm trying to do is open a config file.  For each object this config file references it uses the tags  BEGINOB ENDOB.  I'm trying to read the while thing and Split on ENDOB, and IF the first set contains BEGINOB+"\r\n"+"13" write all the contents to a console line.  I have this code here but i'm having a hard time figure out my split.

```
using (FileStream redfs = new FileStream(redfoldertarget, FileMode.Open))
            using (StreamReader rdrred = new StreamReader(redfs))
            {
                while (!rdrred.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string linesplitnew = "ENDOB";
                    string[] redsplitline = rdrred.ReadToEnd().Split(Convert.ToString(linesplitnew));
                    string redpullline = "BEGINOB"+"\r\n"+"13";
                    if(redsplitline.Contains(redpullline))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(redsplitline);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need to concatenate `redpullline`.  Instead, you can write `string redPullLine = "BEGINOB\r\n13";`

Comment: @Anon: He's calling `Split` wrong, so it won't compile.

Comment: Then it would probably be good to mention "It's not compiling". (And also probably good to take a look at the compiler error given, and then look at the documentation which is very clear on how to call it correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the [`Split` overload that takes an array of strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx), like this:

```
string[] redsplitline = rdrred.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { linesplitnew }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```